# How to make lapply faster in a database with more than 30 millions rows?

Tags: r, database, parallel-processing, data.table, lapply

I  have a very big database (more than 30 millions records) with the following structure:

```
test <- as.data.table(list(v1 = c("150,10001,11,Bien", "151,10002,11,Bien", 
"152,10003,11,Bien", "153,10004,11,Mal", 
"154,10005,11,Regular")))
```

I downloaded that db as one string per row since I miss a lot of information trying to read using `fread` straightforward. For instance, I get errors similar to this: `"Stopped early on line 101. Expected 1099 fields but found 1100. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line"` Because of that I can't download the whole database as expected.

What I want to achieve is to create four variables from those strings.This code works perfectly in my dummy database:

```
test <- test[, `:=`(id = lapply(strsplit(test$v1, split=","), "[", 1),
                              question_id = lapply(strsplit(test$v1, split=","), "[", 2),
                              answer_id = lapply(strsplit(test$v1, split=","), "[", 3),
                              answer = lapply(strsplit(test$v1, split=","), "[", 4))]
```

In my actual database, this code is taking a lot of time. I waited more than two hours and didn't get any result.I guess this approach might be wrong since I'm not creating variables themselves but lists so that makes the process slower than it should be:

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ v1         : chr  "150,10001,11,Bien" "151,10002,11,Bien" "152,10003,11,Bien" "153,10004,11,Mal" ...
 $ id         :List of 5
  ..$ : chr "150"
  ..$ : chr "151"
  ..$ : chr "152"
  ..$ : chr "153"
  ..$ : chr "154"
 $ question_id:List of 5
  ..$ : chr "10001"
  ..$ : chr "10002"
  ..$ : chr "10003"
  ..$ : chr "10004"
  ..$ : chr "10005"
 $ answer_id  :List of 5
  ..$ : chr "11"
  ..$ : chr "11"
  ..$ : chr "11"
  ..$ : chr "11"
  ..$ : chr "11"
 $ answer     :List of 5
  ..$ : chr "Bien"
  ..$ : chr "Bien"
  ..$ : chr "Bien"
  ..$ : chr "Mal"
  ..$ : chr "Regular"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

I read that `parLapply` (a function from `parallel` library) tends to be slower than `lapply` when using Windows so I discarded that solution.
Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: *"miss a lot of information trying to read it the usual way"* ... reading long strings into R has slightly more penalties than some other languages; with 30Mi rows, it may be worth trying to figure out why you cannot read in the rows in the correct way the first time. Further, your use of `tstrsplit` _four times_ is unnecessary, see that `test[, c("id","question_id","answer_id","answer") := tstrsplit(v1, ",")]` does **mostly** the same thing but only doing (expensive-ish) string operations _once_.

Comment: For example, if I use fread, I get errors like this: "Stopped early on line 101. Expected 1099 fields but found 1100. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line" so I can't download the whole database as expected. That's what I mean with "the usual way". Maybe I must specifiy that, thank you.

Comment: `Stopped early on line 101` sounds like one of the rows has an extra comma (or whatever character is used as separator), thus, `fread` thinks that row has an extra column

Comment: @SweepyDodo Exactly. That's why I downloaded the whole database as one string per row and that way I get all observations. Now the problem is to achieve what I want.

Comment: Have you tried setting `fill = TRUE` in `fread()` as suggested by the error message?

Comment: @zephryl Yes and I also get discarded lines. My best approach was to use sep= " " and download the database as one string per row.

Comment: I suspect you can fix the real issue by simply exporting the data from the database with quoted strings.

Comment: It's not guaranteed that `*apply` is faster than a `for` loop in all cases.  You might want to test a small subset of your data both ways.

Answer (score 5):

First, calling `tstrsplit` multiple times on the same strings just to get to specific columns can be avoided:

```r
test <- as.data.table(list(v1 = c("150,10001,11,Bien", "151,10002,11,Bien","152,10003,11,Bien", "153,10004,11,Mal","154,10005,11,Regular")))
test[, c("id","question_id","answer_id","answer") := tstrsplit(v1, ",")][]
#                      v1     id question_id answer_id  answer
#                  <char> <char>      <char>    <char>  <char>
# 1:    150,10001,11,Bien    150       10001        11    Bien
# 2:    151,10002,11,Bien    151       10002        11    Bien
# 3:    152,10003,11,Bien    152       10003        11    Bien
# 4:     153,10004,11,Mal    153       10004        11     Mal
# 5: 154,10005,11,Regular    154       10005        11 Regular
```

Just this change along is 4x faster with this small dataset, and with 1000x as many rows, it actually was more-efficient in limited testing.

(Another comment: using `test$v1` while inside a `test` calculation is inefficient and might be slowing you down a little. Perhaps 1% or so ... not much.)

Since you say you have rows with too many commas, then this will still fail. For those, from your current (too-slow) method that you only want the first four elements of each string, so we can remove it first. I'll modify the sample data so that we can see the effect here.

```r
test <- as.data.table(list(v1 = c("150,10001,11,Bien", "151,10002,11,Bien","152,10003,11,Bien", "153,10004,11,Mal","154,10005,11,Regular")))

test[4, v1 := paste0(v1, ",quux")]
test[, c("id","question_id","answer_id","answer") := tstrsplit(v1, ",")][]
# Error in `[.data.table`(test, , `:=`(c("id", "question_id", "answer_id",  : 
#   Supplied 4 columns to be assigned 5 items. Please see NEWS for v1.12.2.
```

Your currently (too-slow) method suggests that you only want the first four and are willing to discard everything after it, so I'll suggest a conditional `sub`.

```r
test[nchar(gsub("[^,]+", "", v1)) > 3, v1 := sub(",[^,]*$", "", v1)]
test[, c("id","question_id","answer_id","answer") := tstrsplit(v1, ",")][]
#                      v1     id question_id answer_id  answer
#                  <char> <char>      <char>    <char>  <char>
# 1:    150,10001,11,Bien    150       10001        11    Bien
# 2:    151,10002,11,Bien    151       10002        11    Bien
# 3:    152,10003,11,Bien    152       10003        11    Bien
# 4:     153,10004,11,Mal    153       10004        11     Mal
# 5: 154,10005,11,Regular    154       10005        11 Regular
```

However, I think all of that is unnecessary, since you can instruct `fread` to fill when extract columns are discovered (as the warning/error message suggests).

```r
fread("quux.csv")
# Warning in fread("quux.csv") :
#   Stopped early on line 4. Expected 4 fields but found 5. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<153,10004,11,Mal,quux>>
#       V1    V2    V3     V4
#    <int> <int> <int> <char>
# 1:   150 10001    11   Bien
# 2:   151 10002    11   Bien
# 3:   152 10003    11   Bien
fread("quux.csv", fill = TRUE)
#       V1    V2    V3      V4     V5
#    <int> <int> <int>  <char> <char>
# 1:   150 10001    11    Bien       
# 2:   151 10002    11    Bien       
# 3:   152 10003    11    Bien       
# 4:   153 10004    11     Mal   quux
# 5:   154 10005    11 Regular
```

This is certainly a safer path, since it allows you to assess if the extra columns are okay to discard, or if perhaps one of the other columns should have had an embedded comma in a quoted string.